# Identify the common text present in all items within a variable

Tags: r, string

Is there a function to find the common text within in my variables?
Example data

```
V1 <- c("Age = 18-24", "Age = 25-34","Age = 35-44","Age = 45-54","Age = 55+")
V2 <- c("Social Grade A","Social Grade B","Social Grade D","Social Grade E","Social Grade F")
V3 <- c("How often do you do X? - 1 times","How often do you do X? - 2 times","How often do you do X? - 3 or more")
```

I'm working with hundreds of text variables like the above. Within each variable, they have the common text at the left of the text, with the unique part at the right.

Is there a function to identify for V1 that "Age = " is the common text present in all items, and for V2 it is "Social Grade " etc?

Expected output would be equivalent to

```
V1_text <- "Age = "
V2_text <- "Social Grade "
V3_text <- "How often do you do X? - "
```

Comment: Are these the only patterns?

Comment: If you're importing survey data, check for packages specific for your provider. For example, the `qualtRics` package makes importing data from Qualtrics surveys easy, and there are packages for several other survey services.

Comment: I work with hundreds of variables. Within each variable the common part of the text is always on the left side. It is usually the form of "question text - then answer" from questionnaire, so the common part varies in length. There is no standard end point of the common text. Some can be "?" or some can be " - " and other ways, so I can't use that way to get the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a loop to start from the end of the shortest string and check if all the entries match (ie the length of unique values is 1), taking away one letter from the end until they do.

```
find_common_start <- function(strings) {
  max_length = min(nchar(strings))
  for(len in max_length:1) {
    if(length(unique(substr(strings, start = 1, stop = len))) == 1) {
      return(substr(strings[[1]], start = 1, stop = len))
    }
  }
}
```

result

```
> find_common_start(V1)
[1] "Age = "
> find_common_start(V2)
[1] "Social Grade "
> find_common_start(V3)
[1] "How often do you do X? - "
```

Comment: I'm sure this can be done more concisely. Any advice?

Comment: Excellent solution. Have tested it and, at my level, I can just about understand what is going on too. Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the use of the LCSn-function from the PTQXC-package.

explantion of code below:
I used the `lst`-function from the `tibble`-package to easily create a named list of you input data (V1, V2, ... Vn). Then `lapply()` the `LCSn()`-function over this list, and pass the resulting list's contents to the global environgment using `list2env()
**(after altering names, of you will overwrite your source data!)**.

```
library( PTXQC )
library( tibble )

L <- lapply( tibble::lst( V1, V2, V3 ), PTXQC::LCSn )
# $V1
# [1] "Age = "
# $V2
# [1] "Social Grade "
# $V3
# [1] "How often do you do X? - "

names(L) <- paste0( names(L), "_text")
list2env( L, .GlobalEnv )
```

Comment: Heads up: If all your entries in a vector are the same... so in V1 all entries are `"Age = 18-24"`, you will get that exact string as LCS.. (this is also the case I believe in @JonSpring's solution

Comment: thanks for the heads up that's exactly what I'd have expected if all items are identical. Many thanks